# Unix curl command throwing error when it has ( in the password

Tags: unix, curl

I am using `curl` command to upload a file from Unix to a SharePoint. I am passing username and password in the curl command itself. The problem which I am getting is with the password.

My password has `(` in it and the curl command is throwing the below error:

> `Unexpected syntax error '(`

Please help me how i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Special characters has special meaning in `unix` shells. You can either encode the password if acceptable to the server, or escape the offending character so it doesn't get interpreted by the shell. If you had posted a [mcve], you would have gotten several answers already.

Answer (score 0):

If your doing this

```
curl -u username:pswdwith( http://example.com
```

Then the easiest solution should be to escape it:

```
curl -u username:pswdwith\( http://example.com
```

Could also work by quoting it:

```
curl -u 'username:pswdwith(' http://example.com
```

Comment: @nikhilsinha, was this [helpfull](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?